# Submitting form in HTML - redirecting

Tags: html, ajax, forms, http-post

I have a form in my webpage,
The form uploads a file to my server.

currently when the file upload form submits, after the server side finishes saving the image it tries to redirect my webpage to a different page :( (the name of the form action)

is there a way to execute the form without the redirect part? like an ajax call for uploading my image?

thanks.

here is the form:

```
  <form method="POST" action="/project/upload"
  enctype="multipart/form-data">


   Please select a file to upload : <input type="file" name="file" />
   <input type="submit" value="upload" />
   </form>
```

EDIT - Let me try to rephrase it: 
is it possible to submita form in such a way that it wont change my page or redirect?
and is it possible to create a call back when it finishes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `target="iframeName"` on your form to get it to post to an iframe on the page with no reloads occuring. Something a little like this:

```
<form method="POST" action="/project/upload"
  enctype="multipart/form-data" target="myFrame">

..Form content..

</form>

<iframe name="myFrame" height=0 width=0></iframe>
```

Answer (score 0):

Think best way is using a php page which calls itself with no redirect:

```
<form action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];?>" method="post">

....

</form>
```

So you call the same page to do upload and don't need redirect. In other way you can add header in php page  "/project/upload" with automatic redirect to put after upload code:

```
header("location: yourpage.html");
```

Comment: This is actually assumed by a browser if you omit action entirely; i.e. <form method="post"> has the same effect as the above.